# Sql grouping in Temp table and to avoid duplicates repeated on the Result Set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have Framed a Query and declared in to temp .When I run it shows the Duplicate Records when i do the Group By Concept .can you please Guide me .
I have attached my Requirement as Screen Shot with this request .

Thanks for your guidance[output needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfgZl.png)

Comment: How do you recognize duplicates versus needed output?

Comment: I have attached the attachment Out put needed .Please check in the image file.Every card number will have Workorder but here in this logic it is duplicting .So i need to remove that .

Comment: Please add the query you're currently using to your question.

Comment: Thanks..Please share ur email id will share my query it is very big @easuter

Comment: @KumaranN, sorry, I don't share my email on public forums. You can edit your question and include the query there within a code block, or otherwise create a pastebin or gist, and link to that.

Comment: @KumaranN Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with your join. Showing your query would be really useful for solving this issue, but at first glance it looks like you are are doing a FULL JOIN between the 'Work Order' and 'CardNumber' tables where you should be using an INNER JOIN and specifying a value to join on that uniquely ties entries from one table to the other.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number`   window function

```
 select * from 
    (select * ,
    row_number() over(partition by workorder order by cardnumber)as rn 
    from t
    ) t1
    where rn =1
```

Comment: But it gives the Answer for Work Order But the Card Number is same for all the Work Orders.Every Work order Will have unique Card Number .Can you please see the Screen Shot attached in the Question .Thanks for Guidance it was very useful